# Laravel Session is created / generated on every request, Redis takes a lot of space on RAM

Tags: php, laravel, session, redis, sanctum

So I have a Laravel 10 project which is using Sanctum's SPA authentication, which stores sessions to Redis and came to this problem where RAM was suddenly on 100% of usage on server.

When I look in Network tab of Chrome's devtools, I see that session value changes after every request.

I don't call `session()->regenerate()` anywhere nor manipulating session with any manner.

In this case, I tried locally **fixing the file/directory permissions inside `storage` folder** of my app. This showed up like a good idea, because I've seen in Devtools that session value is not changing anymore, it stays the same.

Well, I wanted to be sure so I looked into Redis using `redis-cli`. I executed `FLUSHDB`, made few request to laravel app and then executed

```
KEYS *
```

which ended up logging out a lot of entries - each per request.

My middleware variable inside `app\Http\Kernel.php` looks like this:

```php
protected $middleware = [
        StartSession::class,
        TrustProxies::class,
        PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        ValidatePostSize::class,
        TrimStrings::class,
        ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
];
```

#### **TLDR**; Laravel generates new session every request even though Devtools show same session cookie value.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed this could be because of Cross-origin XHR requests. Before they execute normally as we would await, before every one there is preflight (OPTIONS) request happenning.

This request essentialy must not include cookies, and since we are not including session value, the Laravel's `StartSession` middleware, which is executing on every request, generates new session value and saves it to Redis.

This is the place where all the unknown sessions are generated. So I removed `StartSession` middleware from `$middleware` variable and created new one:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class StartSessionExtended
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return app(StartSession::class)->handle($request, $next);
    }
}
```

What this does is it skips executing `StartSession` middleware when request is of type OPTIONS.